# Identifying this "IC”, Trying to reverse engineer a board

Tags: amplifier, audio, reverse-engineering

**Part 1: the board and how it's connected**

I'm looking at a headphone sound amplifier that is used to help experts detect pests in palm trees when a microphone is placed on the trunk of the palm tree. Here's what the board looks like on the front,

[image: Not a surprise, IC sanded on purpose]

On the left side are 9V battery wires coming in to supply the whole circuit . Top right is ( i presume ) microphone pre-amplifier circuit  which has input from a microphone ( **silver Wire** is the Signal Line while the **bare wire** is ground ) , the output of the BJT microphone circuit (**brown wire**) gets through a potentiometer to the input of the unknown IC (**red wire**) , the IC is then connected to the **purple** and **blue** wires which go to the headphone . The **yellow** and **green** are 9V Lines that are connected / disconnected through a switch .

**Part 2: my conclusions for far**

Here's my guess,

- The BJT circuit is a microphone preamplifier circuit .
- The IC is some sort of a special purpose Audio-ish amplifier .

**Part 3: schematic of the board**

[image: Schematic traced from the PCB]

**Part 4: my questions**

1. What is the IC Model/Type/Category .
2. BJT Circuit drawn earlier ( Preamplfier ? ) .

Comment: The IC marking is unreadable in that photo. Try under a microscope or magnifier with light from an angle.

Comment: This is a nice question with a lot of details. I can't answer, but I want to comment about the potentiometer. Usually it has three connections, you have only drawn two.

Comment: @pjc50 It looks like the marking has been scraped off, either accidentally or on purpose..

Comment: 1. IC Marking is sanded off

Comment: 2. Potentiometer / Switch  Hybrid has the following wires : A.  Yellow : 9V from battery ,  B. Green : 9V at the load side ( Circuit ) , C. Orange : Ground , D. Brown : Microphone BJT Circuit Output , E. Red : Potentiometer Output

Comment: Man, they sanded off the IC marking and the label on the PCB.  They didn't want you to know what it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't be absolutely certain but the IC looks to be a TDA7052  (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA7052.pdf)

[image]

The bjt looks like a pre-amp stage for an electret microphone. Not totally convinced you have the correct circuit but there are lots of similar circuits out there on the net you could use.

for example:

[image]